# Wordpress get posts by tax term- tax term is page slug

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Can someone please help me with this as I am very new to PHP?

I have a custom category with taxonomy and terms:
ie
MAIN GALLERY (Custom Category)
- Gallery One (taxomony 1)
   - Album One (term 1)
   - Album Two (term 2)
- Gallery Two (taxomony 1)

I would like to display all the posts that are in Album 1 (term 1).

I have this code so far: The slug name is printing on the front end but not being used to return the posts, is it this bit
`'terms' => array_shift( $terms )`  ??

I can get this to work if I specify the Term name in the array but I need it to read from the page slug.

As stated I am very new to PHP and probably have structure wrong somewhere, done something to upset the loop or suchlike. Any help greatly appreciated.

CODE:

```
<?php

$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'pubgal' ); // get the term $term = array_shift( $terms );
echo $term->slug;
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pubgal',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array_shift( $terms )
        ),
    ),
    'post_type' => 'gallery'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { 
    $term = $query->queried_object;
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        $query->the_post();
        the_title(); 
        the_content(); 
        the_post_thumbnail(); 
    endwhile; 
}
//RESET YOUR QUERY VARS
wp_reset_query();

?>
```

Comment: CODE:
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'pubgal' );
// get the term
$term = array_shift( $terms );
echo $term->slug;
$args = array(
'tax_query' => array(
array(
'taxonomy' => 'pubgal',
'field' => 'slug',
'terms' => array_shift( $terms )
),),
'post_type' => 'gallery'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
$term = $query->queried_object;
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        the_title();
        the_content();
 the_post_thumbnail();
endwhile;
}

//RESET YOUR QUERY VARS
wp_reset_query();
?>

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through `$terms` to get the `term_id` because you have `fields='all'` in get_terms() (all is thqe default value If you the term id, you'll get it with $term->term_id)

If you put `fields='ids` you'll be able to ask the `tax_query` with $terms directly (eventually with array_shift if need).